# Weekly job to create or update the lessons in all locations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm working in a project with the following structure.

A location can have many timetables with many lessons.

I need to perform a job in all locations every sunday to create or update the lessons.

```
def perform(*args)
    locations = Location.all
    locations.each do |location|
      timetables = LocationLessonService.fetch(location.id)["timetables"]
      timetables.each do |timetable|
        lessons = timetable["lessons"]
        lessons.each do |lesson|
          Lesson.find_or_initialize_by(external_id: lesson['external_id'])
            .update_attributes(period.merge(location_id: location.id))
        end
      end  
    end
  end
```

Is it possible to remove this nested iteration?Is it possible to optimize this function using the gem virtus or something else?

Comment: What is `*args` for? Seems irrelevant. Are these classes ActiveRecord models, or something else? What about `LocationLessonService` — is it your own code, or a third-party remote API? It's hard to advise you how to improve the code without knowing contextual information like that.

Comment: This is a sidekiq worker.
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Comment: All classes are ActiveRecord models and this service is my own piece of code to consume the data of timetables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as written is fine.  And I say that as hater of all things nested.
One way or the other, you *have* nested loops.  One option is to retain that
structure explictly, as it currently is, but to clean it up by removing temporary
named variables that add clutter but not clarity:

```
def perform(*args)
  Location.all.each do |location|
    timetables = LocationLessonService.fetch(location.id)["timetables"]
    timetables.each do |timetable|
      timetable["lessons"].each do |lesson|
        Lesson.find_or_initialize_by(external_id: lesson['external_id'])
          .update_attributes(period.merge(location_id: location.id))
      end
    end  
  end
end
```

What makes it difficult to tease these loops apart into named methods is 
that the innermost loop references the `location.id` from the outermost loop.

That said, I'm wondering why the location isn't simply a property of the timetable?
Or can the same timetable exist in multiple locations?  Because if the location
were a property of the timetable, you wouldn't have the problem I mentioned in 
the last paragraph.

That is to say, while I don't consider the code itself problematic, there may
be better ways to organize your data.  But it's hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: This is the data structure that the programmers who created the project used.
Each location has its own timetables.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to break out the nested loops using `map` to create snapshots of the array at different points in the transformation and then reference those using `with_index`.

```
  def perform(*args)
    locations = Location.all
    timetables = locations.map do |location|
      LocationLessonService.fetch(location.id)["timetables"]
    end
    lessons = timetables.map { |timetable| timetable["lessons"] }
    lessons.each_with_index do |lesson, index|
       location = locations[index]
       Lesson.find_or_initialize_by(external_id: lesson['external_id'])
             .update_attributes(period.merge(location_id: location.id))
    end
  end
```